# bash : replace text with partially-space-filled string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file of the following format.

```
33256SOL    OW 100092   1.507   1.186   0.847
33256SOL    HW1100093   1.561   1.233   0.783
...
```

And I would like to change it to

```
33256SOL    OW     92   1.507   1.186   0.847
33256SOL    HW1    93   1.561   1.233   0.783
...
```

I would like to do a for loop in bash. However, the formatting was wrong. There is no space filling for a consistent format.

```
for i in {100001..200000}; do
        j=$(expr $i - 100000)
        sed -i "s/$i/$j/g" number.txt
done
```

Is there anyway to fill the variable with space and put it in sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F"[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" '{$2=substr($2,1,3) " " substr($2,4)-100000}1' file
```

The output:

```
33256SOL OW  92 1.507 1.186 0.847
33256SOL HW1 93 1.561 1.233 0.783
```

---

- `-F"[[:space:]][[:space:]]+"` - field separator (by multiple spaces)
- `substr($2,1,3)` - get the first 3 characters of the 2nd field
- `substr($2,4)-100000` - subtract `100000` from 6-difit number of the 2nd field

---

To obtain tab-formatted output just add the OFS (output field separator) like below:

```
awk -F"[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" -v OFS="\t" '{$2=substr($2,1,3)" "substr($2,4)-100000}1' file
```

The output:

```
33256SOL    OW  92  1.507   1.186   0.847
33256SOL    HW1 93  1.561   1.233   0.783
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
However, my file needs to have exactly the format due to later on processing, i.e. there must be exactly 4 space between 33256SOL and OW. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Ok, this is better! :)

Comment: @Simon, that's not a problem, change to `-v OFS="4 spaces"`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Sorry I should have mentioned it from the beginning. I have just uploaded other pieces of my file. I hope this will clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
cat number.txt | cut -c -15 > prefix
cat number.txt | cut -c 16- | awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $1 - 100000, $2, $3, $4}' | paste prefix -
```

First line recover first part of line we don't want to change.
Second line take part of line we want to change (`cut`), change it (`awk`), and paste part previously recover by first line (`paste`).